# speed up code to get companies within a radius and sum them up in R

Tags: r, datatable, coordinates

I have two datatables. One with house locations d8.small (East-coordinate, North-coordinate, streetname, and id number) and one with numbers of companies STATENT (East-coordinate, North-coordinate, and numbers of companies) within a hectar.

```
d8.small[1:5, .(GKODE,GKODN,strasse, id)]
     GKODE   GKODN           strasse       id
1: 2608850 1262583      hauptstrasse      100
2: 2612952 1267232 ramsteinerstrasse 10000012
3: 2612952 1267232 ramsteinerstrasse 11776807
4: 2623360 1247413  mosermattstrasse 10000061
5: 2622938 1259411      im pfauenhof 10000223
```

```
STATENT[1:5, .(E_KOORD,N_KOORD,`Arbeitsstätten Total`)]
   E_KOORD N_KOORD Arbeitsstätten Total
1: 2486200 1111300                    3
2: 2486200 1111500                    3
3: 2486300 1111000                    3
4: 2486300 1111700                    3
5: 2486400 1111600                    3
```

I need in the first datatable a new column with the number of companies within 2000 meters.

My current approach seems to work but it is very slow: How can i speed this up?

```
d8.small[,
         c("idex_vollzeitstellen") := {
            dist = (GKODE - STATENT[["E_KOORD"]])^2 + (GKODN - STATENT[["N_KOORD"]])^2 
            .(sum(STATENT$`Arbeitsstätten Total`[sqrt(dist < 25000000)]))},by = id]
```

Comment: Maybe `merge/cbind`,calculate and `filter`? Could you elaborate which column represents what maybe by adding a comment?

Comment: @NelsonGon I added the description of each column in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
d8.small = fread('GKODE   GKODN           strasse       id
 2608850 1262583      hauptstrasse      100
 2612952 1267232 ramsteinerstrasse 10000012
 2612952 1267232 ramsteinerstrasse 11776807
 2623360 1247413  mosermattstrasse 10000061
 2622938 1259411      impfauenhof 10000223', header=TRUE)

STATENT = fread('   E_KOORD N_KOORD Arbeitsstätten Total
2486200 1111300         NA           3
 2486200 1111500        NA            3
 2486300 1111000        NA            3
 2486300 1111700        NA            3
 2486400 1111600        NA            3', header=TRUE)

d8.small[, check := 1]
STATENT[, check := 1]
d8.small = merge(d8.small, STATENT, by='check', how='left', allow.cartesian = T)
d8.small[, dist := ifelse((GKODE - E_KOORD)^2 + (GKODN - N_KOORD)^2 < 2000^2, 1, 0)]
d8.small[, sum(dist), id]
```